# How to set default TAX

Tags: tax, default

I only have one TAX option but when entering new product I'm forced to set the TAX option.

Is there a way set a TAX value to default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is changing a value in Magento Database

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `default_value` = '2' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`='tax_class_id';
```

By default is set as **NULL** So change `default_value = 'Your value tax'`

If you inspect Taxes Dropdrop you will find `Tax Value`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could add a small custom module, MyModule\Taxdefault

This way you have some history and deployment covered.

app/etc/modules/MyModule_Taxdefault.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Taxdefault>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </MyModule_Taxdefault>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyModule/Taxdefault/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Taxdefault>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyModule_Taxdefault>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_taxdefault>
                <setup>
                    <module>MyModule_Taxdefault</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </mymodule_taxdefault>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyModule/Taxdefault/sql/mymodule_taxdefault/install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

// Will update the attribute
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product','tax_class_id','default_value',YOUR_WANTED_TAX_CLASS_ID);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Its not working, correctly...

Comment: it should be `updateAttribute()` instead of `addAttribute()`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your sql_db and find the record "tax_class_id" in the table "eav_attribute" and update the field "default_value" with the desired value.